# Bash Function Oblivion

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc

I'm fairly new to Linux, as many of you may have noticed. What I speak particularly is adding personal, user-generated functions and alias in my .bashrc file. I'm not exactly sure how bash works but according to many posts I "add it to the end of my .bashrc file." Which does not work when the command is executed through the Terminal.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Your last questions (about how/where to learn) are [off topic](http://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask) here. We only deal with specific, concrete problems, and requests for learning materials are too broad (I have therefore deleted that part of your question). Your first question is fine but please [edit] and show us an example of a function you've added, explain what it's supposed to do and how it is failing.

Answer (score 1):

For login shells, `.profile` in your home directory will be executed. So if you have functions defined in `.bashrc`, make sure the file is included in `.profile` as below:

```
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi
```

Also, you can issue the command below:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

and then call your functions. This will make sure there is no problem in including any files.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you open a new terminal, all the commands in your .bashrc are carried out (the file is 'sourced'). If you add a new command to your .bashrc, you need to either open a new terminal or issue one of the following commands:

```
. ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

For example, you could put on a new line (each command has to be on a new line -- well, that's actually a simplification, but it's enough for an absolute beginner to be getting on with) at the end of your .bashrc something like:

```
alias hello='echo "Hello, $USER"'
```

...then, once you've either opened a new, fresh terminal window or used one of the source commands, you should be able to type `hello` and get a greeting back from your machine.

If you are doing all this and the functions/aliases don't work, then there's probably something wrong with the specific functions or aliases that you're using. If you suspect that's the case, feel free to ask a separate question.

As for tutorials, one I found very clear and useful when I was starting out with bash was [linuxcommand](http://linuxcommand.org).